# How to disable adding Hash to thumbnail url

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a problem when PS 1.7.6 sometimes adds a hash in my thumbnails url. After PS adding these hashes - thumbnails start to be missing. Here is where the Hash is added:

> example.com/1339-home_default-**qybdedIWgk**/uniq-one-sampunas-balzamas-revlon.jpg

and original is:

> example.com/1339-home_default/uniq-one-sampunas-balzamas-revlon.jpg

How to disable adding that hash without disabling all SEO compatibility? Because when I turn off SEO links, it disappears, but also disappears all needed SEO functions.

UPDATE

Many photos has friendly-url-autogeneration-failed.jpg name, but still displayed on the website...

UPDATE 2.
This hash added only after some time when browsing in the website, so maybe it is going from cache?

Comment: do you use any watermark module?

Comment: Yes, stadard free PS water mark module v. 2.0.0. But it adds watermark only on "large_default (800 x 800)" size image on ClassicTheme, and this size of image is found. Only thumbnails are missing. Missing maybe because watermark module isn't creating thumbnails with watermark so they are missing after hash is added?  Which part of PS adding this hash? Thank you!!!

Comment: This hash appears always in the same block?

Comment: @joseantgv yes, in the same block

Comment: Probably this block is not retrieving URL correctly. Which block is it? Could you paste the code?